# android: Visualization of sound from Spotify

Tags: android, spotify, visualizer

Im using the android.media.audiofx.Visualizer class to visualize music on my android device. Im using the Visualizer constructor with session ID = 0 so the audio output mix is used as datasource but it do not work with Spotify. Google Play Music works like expected but I want to visualize Spotify audio. Can I do this or is spotify using some kind of work around for music output?

With spotify I get in the onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) method only 0 in the byte array and with onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) I get the values -128 in the byte array.

Comment: Which Android version are you testing this on? IIRC, the AudioFlinger used to suspend effects on session 0 if some app enabled an effect on a non-zero session. This has been modified in Android 4.4 so that the Visualizer won't be suspended.

Comment: Im using kitkat (4.4) on nexus 4

Comment: I don't know if I'm using the Visualizer class wrong or do I miss understand you Michael? Are you saying that it should work under Android 4.4 (KitKat). The code I'm using is available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9A79BNQVcd-VjU2OUo4cExCdG8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: To clarify what I mean. The code above works fine with Google Play Music but not with Spotify.

Comment: The visualization does not work with VLC either.

Comment: Right, I would've expected it to work on Kitkat. So the problem is probably not what I thought it was.

Comment: I tried the code a posted above on a emulator running Amdroid 2.3.3 and the Spotify apk from my phone. it works like it should. I get the audiodata in my Visualizer. So there is something with Android and not spotify that doing some kind of black magic.

Comment: I wrote a small app that loops a audio clip and tried to break the visualization but I could not find any effect that breaks the visulization. The effects I tried is: BassBoost, PresetReverb, EnvironmentalReverb and Equalizer. Anyone that can think of somekind of audio effect that I missed? The Visualizer is attached to session ID 0. Please download the code I used and break that visualizer under Android 4.x. If would be nice if we could isolate the problem. The code I used can be downloaded from this location: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9A79BNQVcd-SUJBc1F1SEhtQ2s/edit?usp=sharing